# Slicing and Replacing Unicode String Characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, slice

I have the following loop I'm trying to use to replace characters in a unicode string. The data I'm getting for this loop is in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

This data is apparently stored in UTC, so when I grab it and append these times & dates to my list `appts_list` its 4 hours ahead.

I've gotten as far as slicing the unicode string and doing the math on these characters and getting what would be the correct hour I need, but I'm having a problem getting that back into a string so I can write it to my list `appts_list`.

I'm getting TypeError when I try to write the integer for the correct hour `time_slice_int` back into the original string. I decided to try to put the entire string into a list and change them there, but that isn't working either.

Ideally I want an appointment for '2013-06-28 15:30:00' to be entered into my `appts_list` as '2013-06-28 11:30:00'.

The print statements are there for me to debug as I ran it. They are not necessary for the final version.

Anyone have any suggestions or solutions?

```
for appt in todays_appts:
        time = appt['apptdateourtime_c']
        time_slice = time[11:13]
        time_slice_int = int(time_slice)
        time_slice_int -= 4
        print(time_slice_int)
        appt_time = list(time)
        print(appt_time)
        print(appt_time[11:13])
        #appt_time[11:13] = time_slice_int
        #appts_list.append()
        print('AppointmentScheduled')
        #print(appt['apptdateourtime_c'])
        #print(time)
        print('')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module here:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> strs = '2013-06-28 15:30:00'
>>> d = datetime.strptime(strs, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

[`datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) returns a datetime object:

```
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 28, 15, 30)
>>> d.hour
15
>>> d.month
6
```

Now decrease 4  hours from the above datetime object(`d`) using [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) and assign the new object to a variable:

```
>>> d1 = d - timedelta(hours = 4)
```

Now use [`datetime.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to get a string of required format:

```
>>> datetime.strftime(d1,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2013-06-28 11:30:00'
```

Comment: Could I use the unicode object like this:
`appt_time = datetime.datetime(appt['apptdateourtime_c'])`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about `datetime.strptime`! Can you tell me why I'm getting 2013-06-28T08:30:00 as the result? It's putting a 'T' in there.

Comment: @novafluxx Even I am not sure why you're getting a `T` there.

Comment: No problem. I know I was going about it totally wrong. I love the standard library. I'll read up on [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: @novafluxx I don't think so, you can encode that string to normal string using `encode`. `appt['apptdateourtime_c'].encode('ascii')` and try again. If your issue is still not resolved then post a new question.
`

Comment: I found out why there is the "T" character: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations